# running many CREATE VIEW and GRANT SELECT statements in one execution

Tags: sql-server, ssms, view

Is there a way to run multiple CREATE VIEW commands and/or multiple GRANT SELECT commands by hitting F5 in SQL Server Management Studio?  If so, how can I do this?

Comment: You just need the batch terminator, which in SSMS is `GO` unless you altered this default

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiple CREATE VIEW statements can be executed together if you separate them with keyword 'GO'

```
CREATE VIEW vw_test1 AS SELECT name FROM dbo.test1;
GO
CREATE VIEW vw)test2 AS SELECT name FROM dbo.test2;
GO
GRANT SELECT ON vw_test....
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use dynamic SQL. Encapsulate your CREATE VIEW and/or GRANT SELECT statement in text.
ex:

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(50)
  SET @Query = 'CREATE VIEW ... '
  exec sp_executesql @Query
```

You can do that for all the queries you need to run and then just press F5